# When is ($\int_X g)^{1/p} \geq \int_{A} (g)^{1/p}$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

For the following, consider an arbitrary measure space $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ In trying to prove that convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence in measure, I came accross [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281421/convergence-in-lp-implies-convergence-in-measure). Now I'm trying to understand the proof given, I got stuck when it says
$$
\Big(\int _X \vert f_n-f\vert ^p\Big)^{1/p} \ge \int_{A_{n,\varepsilon}}\Big(\vert f_n-f\vert ^p\Big)^{1/p}
$$
I see why it would be so that
$$
\Big(\int _X \vert f_n-f\vert ^p\Big)^{1/p} \ge \Big(\int_{A_{n,\varepsilon}}\vert f_n-f\vert ^p \Big)^{1/p}
$$
(exponent outside the integral). Since $A_{k,\varepsilon}\subset X$. Moreover, I also wonder about the more general result given in the question title. Any help apreciated.

Comment: For finite measure spaces, use Jensen's inequality. I think it's likely you want to replace $p$ by $1/p$ throughout...

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean to ask when

$$\int_X g \ge \left(\int_X g^p\right)^{1/p}$$

holds, since you mentioned $L^p$ norms. Assuming that $g$ is a positive function, this does not hold in very many circumstances. If $X$ has measure $1$, Jensen's inequality implies the reverse inequality and $g$ must be constant on $X$. If $X$ has measure greater than $1$, then apply this argument to measure-1 subsets of $X$. If $X$ has measure less than $1$, then study the measure $\tilde{\mu} := \mu / \mu(X)$.

---

But for what it's worth, none of that is being used in the linked question, since there's no comparison of $L^1$ and $L^p$ norms. Monotonicity of the $L^p$ norm is the only thing really getting used.

Comment: I meant it as I worte it, only forgot to add that $A \subset X$.