# Problem on property of sequences of functions in Lp spaces

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I was going through the problems from an exam in Measure and Integration Theory and I stumbled upon a problem that stumped me. It is as follows:

> Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $p_1, p_2 \ge 1, f_n \in L^{p_1}(X)$ and $g_n \in L^{p_2}(X)$ such that $||f_n||_{p_1} \rightarrow 0$ and $||g_n||_{p_2}\rightarrow 0$.
>   Show that $f_n g_n$
>   converges to $0$ almost everywhere (with respect to $\mu$).
>   Does the
>   statement remain true if, instead of $f_n$ converging in the $L^{p_1}$
>   norm and $f_n \in L^{p_1}(X)$ we have the condition that $f_n$
>   converges almost everywhere?

I tried applying Hölder's inequality with various coefficients but to no avail and I'm not sure what else I could try. Am I being really dumb and missing something?

Answer (score 0):

$\|f_n\|_{p_1} \to 0$ and $\|g_n\|_{p_2} \to 0$ do not imply that $f_ng_n$ tends to $0$ almost everywhere. Unless this part is corrected the question does not make much sense. [There is a standard example of a sequence $f_n$ such that $0 \leq f_n \leq 1$, $\|f_n\|_1 \to 0$ but $f_n$ does not tend to $0$ almost everywhere. Take $g_n=f_n$ to get a counterexample].

Comment: What would that counterexample be, if you don't mind? Also, would it be true if one or both of the $p_i$ were strictly greater than 1?

Comment: Arrange the characteristic functions of dyadic intervals $(\frac {i-1} {2^{n}},\frac 1 {2^{n}})$ ($1\leq i \leq 2^{n}, n\geq 1$) is a sequence.

Comment: What about this, though? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281421/convergence-in-lp-implies-convergence-in-measure

Comment: Convergence in measure is different from conveegence almost everywhere. @anonimnystefy

Comment: Ah, my bad, I meant the former.