# If $f_p \rightarrow f$ in weak $L^P$, then is it true that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-lp-spaces

If $f_n \rightarrow f$ in weak $L^p$, then is it true that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure?

Where the weak $L^p$ norm is given by: $[f]_p   =  \sup_{t>0} t \mu(\{x : |f(x)| > t \})^{\frac{1}{p}} < \infty$.

I've been having very little success finding a proof or counter example. It's hard for me to wrap my mind around the weak $L^p$ norm. I'd appreciate any insight!! Thanks

Comment: Did you mean $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$?

Comment: No, but my statement may not be true. If it's not true I'd like a counter example. My inquiry is stated correctly though.

Comment: I thought it's the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1281421/321264.

Comment: No, it's different, but I appreciate the link!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the inequality$$
\mu\left\{x: \lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert \gt \varepsilon\right\}\leqslant \varepsilon^{-p} [f_n-f]_p^p.
$$

Comment: So we have:

$\mu\left\{x: \lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert \gt \varepsilon\right\}\leqslant \varepsilon^{-p} [f_n-f]_p^p=\epsilon^{-p} \sup_{t>0} t \mu(\{x : |f(x)| > t \})$

Is there a reason this inequality is obvious?

Comment: In your comment, it should be $t^p$ and not $t$ appearing after the $\sup$. Perhaps that makes it more obvious?